# Count data model but also dealing with multiple comparison ?

Tags: multiple-comparisons, sas

I'm working on a project dealing with different treatments on the number of medical service in 1 year.

I used negative binomial regression to estimate incident rate ratio after adjusting other confounding factors in this problem.

Because there are more than 2 levels in the treatment arm, I'm trying to consider multiple comparisons in this situation.

## My question:

How could I use PROC GENMOD in SAS to estimate IRR but also consider multiple comparisons in this situation?
or if any R package more suitable in this situation?

Thanks a lot ~

Answer (score 1):

You have in principle several possible approaches to deal with this type of multiple comparisons. If you primarily need adjusted p-values, then a range of multiple testing procedures (e.g. the very conservative Bonferroni, the uniformly more powerful Bonferroni-Holm, weighted Bonferroni-Holm, or the various procedures that exploit the correlations when testing versus a common control - if that is what you are doing - such as the Dunnet test are options). You can do some of these within your SAS procedure (e.g. the Bonferroni test using the LSMESTIMATE statement with the ADJUST option), but all of these can also be easily programm by hand based on extracting the p-values.

Alternatively, there are resampling/bootstrapping based methods that attempt to figure out the correlation between the test statistics for the comparisons you do from the data (e.g. in SAS you should read the documentation for the LSMESTIMATE statement and particularly the ADJUST=SIMULATE(SEED=1234) option, as well as the associated references).

Adjusted confidence intervals tend to be somewhat harder (except for those matching a Bonferroni or weighted Bonferroni test), but I believe some progress has been made in that area more recently.

Or do you also want in some sense adjusted estimates? If so, then methods such as e.g. hierarchical models, the horseshoe prior or many other methods are applicable (there is for example a convenient implementation of the horseshoe prior in the brms R package).